# how to search an Id using hibernate query by example?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, query-by-example

hi i have the following class

```
public class Label
    {
    private Long TableId;
    private Long Id;
    private String LabelName;
    //getters and setters for corresponding fields
    }
```

i was supposed to search on multiple fields dynamically 
i came across hibernate query by example construct my code looks like some thing

```
Label bean =new Label();
if(Id!=null)
{
       bean.setId(Id);
}
if(LabeName!=null)
{
bean.setLabelName(LabelName)
}
    System.out.println(bean.toString());
            Example exampleObject=Example.create(bean).ignoreCase();
             criteria=currentSessionObj.createCriteria(Label.class).add(exampleObject);
             retObjects=criteria.list();
```

when i'm searching on LabelName field i'm getting the exact response when when **i tried to search by id**  i'm getting unexpected results 
i have goggled many forums i couldn't get what i want some one please help me
how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples)

> Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored. By default, null valued properties are excluded.